# Строка SVG не отображается внутри clipPath

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, анимация

У меня есть следующий     [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/KJgjKg?editors=0010)    , где я пытаюсь анимировать строку круга вокруг изображения.

Пока  у меня есть круг SVG, который обрезает изображение, но не показывает строку внутри `clipPath`.

Как мне показать границу?

`class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <svg width='48' height='48'>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='24' r='23' fill='none' stroke='red' strokeWidth='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width='48' height='48' xlinkHref={'https://source.unsplash.com/random'} clipPath='url(#circleView)' />
      </svg>
    )
  }
}`

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54431301/7394871

Answer (score 3):

У дочерних фигур SVG входящих в `clip-path` строки не отображаются.

Поэтому в этом конкретном случае

```
<clipPath id='circleView'>
    circle cx='24' cy='24' r='23' fill='none' 
    stroke='red' stroke-width='2' />
</clipPath>
```

у дочернего элемента `<circle>` красная строка `stroke='red'` будет не видна

Для анимации необходимо добавить ещё одну окружность вне `clip-path`

`<circle cx="25" cy="24" r="14" fill="none" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />`

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <svg  viewBox="0 0 48 48" >
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' 
            stroke='red' stroke-width='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%"   xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
  <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='2' /> 
</svg>
  </div>
```

Для анимации окружности используется изменение атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения до нуля.  `values="(100.48;0)"`

*Анимация начинается после клика по картинке*

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
     <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
    <circle  transform="rotate(-90 24 22)" cx="24" cy="22" r="16" fill='none' stroke='red' strokeWidth='2' 
            stroke-dasharray="100.48"   stroke-dashoffset="100.48" >
            <animate
              attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
              dur="1s"
              begin="svg1.click"
              values="100.48;0"
              fill="freeze"/>
    </circle>       
      </svg>

  </div>
```

### Вариант анимации с CSS

Я добавил к анимации строки окружности анимацию прозрачности:

*Анимация начинается после наведения курсора*

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
   }  
   #crc1 {
   fill:skyblue;
   stroke-width:1;
   stroke:red;
   stroke-dasharray:100.48;
   stroke-dashoffset:100.48;
    fill-opacity:0.9;
     }
   
   #crc1:hover {
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-out forwards;
      }
      
    @keyframes dash {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 100.48; fill-opacity:0.9; }
  50% { fill-opacity:0.45;}
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill-opacity:0; }
   }
   
   #img1 {
   clip-path: url(#circleView);
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
                
      </svg>

  </div>
```

### Вариант анимации  картинок в галерее 3х3

*Примечание

Этого примера нет на Enso*

Принцип действия тот же, что и для одиночного примера.
Пример может быть использован, как заготовка для своего веб дизайна.

**Приложение адаптивно, но  лучше смотреть в полно экранном варианте.**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  width: 32vw;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
  background: #FFDD1B;
} 

   #crc1 {
   fill:skyblue;
   stroke-width:1;
   stroke:red;
   stroke-dasharray:100.55;
   stroke-dashoffset:100.55;
    fill-opacity:0.95;
     }
   
   #crc1:hover {
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-out forwards;
      }
      
    @keyframes dash {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 100.55; fill-opacity:0.95; }
  50% { fill-opacity:0.45;}
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill-opacity:0; }
   }
   
   #img1 {
   clip-path: url(#circleView);
     }
```

```html
<div> 
  <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
  </svg>
</div>
  <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image  y="2" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BhWN.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
  </div> 
     <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image y="5" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLC1p.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>
       
    <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image x="1" y="4" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/FArvR.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>  
       
   <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JK8h.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>  
    
    <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image y="2" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/eROf7.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>  

    <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201408/25/1297423/37.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>  
    
    <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image y="6" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201408/25/1297423/32.jpg" 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>  
    
    <div> 
      <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
       <image y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201408/25/1297423/26.jpg' 
            clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
      </svg>  
    </div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433630/7394871) @Alexandr_TT

Comment: Интересно, надо попробывать такое со слайдером сделать. Хотя может быть перебор с анимацией. Спасибо за пошаговое объяснение.

Comment: @L.F.C. Тут же два варианта: 1. анимация строки обводки и 2. строка + прозрачность   Можно выбрать, который попроще